# Javascript Objects - is not a function

Tags: javascript

I am working my way through objects and I come across this example on codeacademy, bob was pre-done, and my goal was to replicate susan and set her age to 35. I prefered to use the literal notation, but I get an error(susan.setAge is not a function). Why doesn't it recognize setAge as a function now?

```
// here we define our method using "this", before we even introduce bob
var setAge = function (newAge) {
  this.age = newAge;
};
// now we make bob
var bob = new Object();
bob.age = 30;
bob.setAge = setAge;

// make susan here, and first give her an age of 25
var susan = {
  age: 25  
};
// here, update Susan's age to 35 using the method
susan.setAge(35);
```

Comment: It is because susan doesn't how a method called `setAge`. Only Bob has one

Comment: You never added a setAge method to Susan

Comment: isnt the method global? not specific to bob?

Comment: What happened to `alice`?

Comment: Please do some research before asking on SO. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_a_function

Comment: @ChrisCundick: If the method were global, then why would the line `bob.setAge = setAge;` exist?

Answer (score 2):

You need to define the `setAge()` method for Susan as well:

```js
// here we define our method using "this", before we even introduce bob
var setAge = function(newAge) {
  this.age = newAge;
};
// now we make bob
var bob = new Object();
bob.age = 30;
bob.setAge = setAge;

// make susan here, and first give her an age of 25
var susan = {
  age: 25,
  setAge: setAge
};
// here, update Susan's age to 35 using the method
susan.setAge(35);


console.log(susan.age);
```

Comment: In ES6, the `: setAge` is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to share functionality among objects, you can create a `class` and from that class create instances. JavaScript uses `prototypes` for this intention:

```
var Person = function(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
};

Person.prototype.setAge = function(age){
    this.age = age;
};

var bob = new Person("Bob", 35);
bob.setAge(40);

var susan = new Person("Susan", 30);
susan.setAge(25);
```

That way you can reuse your objects.
If you want one-time objects create them using

`var obj = {};`

but if you want to reuse your objects and group them in a class, define a class and its methods on the respective `prototype`.
Still you can add individual methods to an object, even though it has a prototype:

`susan.setName = function(name){ this.name = name; } // now only the susan object has this function`

Find more about prototypes at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes